# Azure - MVC Redirecting non-WWW to WWW Does't work on non root pages

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, redirect

I have an MVC site running on Azure with Front Door, and when I type https://example.com/about, the page times out. The redirect works if it's only https://example.com. Ideas why the '/about' causes the redirect not to work?

```
var options = new RewriteOptions()
             .AddRedirectToHttpsPermanent()
             .AddRedirectToWwwPermanent();
app.UseRewriter(options);
```

Comment: I resolved the issue by adding the Azure IP for the A record (godaddy had it parked) and all worlds as expected now.

Comment: Good to post this as an answer to help the community with the same type of issue. @Todd